# How to share controller actions/view with other controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to call the MainController.GetData() action from a few different URLs without a bunch of copied/pasted code. Is there a preferred way people tackle this? Seems like I might be able to do it with routing as well. I would just like to reuse the view and action since all that code would be the same if I made a version for the GetMyData() action.

```
**Example urls**

*/main/getdata  
/other/getmydata  
/diffferent/getothersdata?userid=3



public ActionResult MainController::GetData()
{
    var data = GetData();
    return View(collection);
}

public ActionResult OtherController::GetMyData()
{
    var userId = GetCurrentUserId();
    var data = GetData(userId);
    return View("../main/getdata", collection);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although controllers look like simple classes, their behavior inside the MVC framework is more specialized. You can't, or perhaps it's better to say you shouldn't, just call an action from one in an action for another, as if it's just any old method. Mostly, this is because controllers have context, and you have to instantiate them and set them up just right so that everything works. That's non-trivial to do inside of an action method and it's going to make your code ugly as hell.

You have two choices really. If you just want the result of the action, the best method is to utilize `HttpClient` and actually submit an HTTP request for it, just like any other request that would activate it.

However, based on your problem description, option two is probably more appropriate. You can create a base class and then inherit from that. For example, if you know two controllers are both going to need `GetData`, you can do something like:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IEnumerable<Data> QueryData(int? userId = null)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class MainController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = QueryData();
        return View(data);
    }
}

public class OtherController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult GetMyData()
    {
        var userId = GetCurrentUserId();
        var data = QueryData(userId);
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

In other words, you factor out the common functionality into something both the actions on both derived controllers can use.

This is all you needed for this scenario, but you can also implement entire actions on the base controller. For example, if you added a `Foo` action to `BaseController`, both `MainController` and `OtherController` would then responds to requests for `Foo`, without having to actually explicitly define that. You can then also override these actions if you need to, as well.

Comment: I like the base controller idea. I think it'll keep the code clean and I'll be able to reuse the action code and the view. I'll accept this one unless some other cleaner solution is presented. Thank you!